# ASP.NET - Obter valor seleccionado de Dropdownlist no meu Controlador

Tags: asp.net

Tenho uma dropdownlist que é definida na minha view da seguinte forma:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Exame", ViewBag.Exame as SelectList, "Escolha uma
 opção...", new { @class = "form-control", @name="ExameARegistar" })
```

Esta dropdownlist deve permitir um utilizador registado se inscrever num exame a partir de uma lista. Para tal, vou necessitar de obter o valor seleccionado a partir do meu controlador.

Tentei usar o `Request.Form["ExameARegistar"]` mas ele devolve sempre null. Gostaria de perceber o que está a causar este erro. Senão, gostaria de saber se existe uma alternativa melhor ao Request.Form...

Comment: Já rentou `Form["Exame"]`, que é o que está definido no `DropDownList`?

Comment: Request.Form["Exame"]? Sim, já tentei. E acontece o mesmo...

Comment: Tentou passar como parâmetro na Action,  `public ActionResult SuaAction(string ExameARegistar)`?

Comment: @Barbetta ainda não. Vou tentar. Como é que faço para passar o valor seleccionado como argumento de entrada no botão submit? 

Este é o meu botão já agora: <input type="submit" value="Adicionar Exame" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AdicionarExame", "Candidaturas")' " />

Comment: Está usando ASP.NET MVC ou WebForms?

Answer (score -1):

Acabei por contornar este problema usando uma variável escondida: https://forums.asp.net/t/1998919.aspx?Access+hidden+value+from+View+to+Controller